# How can I write correct query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
   WITH Encashment AS (
        SELECT  T.MachineId, T.Amount, CAST(Occured AS DATETIME) AS Occured
        FROM (VALUES 
              (1, 101, '2017-10-20 09:36:40.057')
             ,(1, 203, '2017-10-14 12:36:30.081')
             ,(1, 400, '2017-10-11 04:17:38.023')
             ) AS T(MachineId, Amount, Occured)
    ), MoneyAccepted  AS (
        SELECT  T.MachineId, T.Amount, CAST(Occured AS DATETIME) AS Occured
        FROM (VALUES 
              (1, 1, '2017-10-15 09:36:40.057')
             ,(1, 100, '2017-10-16 12:36:30.081')
             ,(1, 100, '2017-10-12 16:17:38.023')
             ,(1, 1, '2017-10-13 09:37:47.057')
             ,(1, 1, '2017-10-13 09:37:47.057')
             ,(1, 1, '2017-10-12 15:37:47.057')
             ,(1, 100, '2017-09-15 12:37:31.081')
             ,(1, 100, '2017-09-15 16:37:31.081')
             ,(1, 100, '2017-09-16 13:37:31.081')
             ,(1, 100, '2017-09-17 13:37:31.081')
             ) AS T(MachineId, Amount, Occured)
    )
```

I can get Amount among two encashment.(`Select Amount from Encashment`).
But, I want to get amount from MoneyAccepted for every Encashment.
For example: Encashment happened in 20-10-2017,till this dateTime accepted
 101(100(2017-10-16 12:36:30.081)+1(2017-10-15 09:36:40.057)) money.
How can I get that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: post expected output for the data

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I used the below query, but it isn't work correctly.
Select *,ISNULL((SELECT Occured FROM Encashment WHERE Occured = ( SELECT MAX(Occured)  FROM Encashment
               WHERE Occured < ( SELECT MAX(Occured) 
                              FROM Encashment 
                            ) and MachineID=s.MachineID
             )),'2017-01-01')kk from Encashment s 
    
     where s.MachineID='1' order by s.Occured desc,MachineID

Comment: Have a look at [How to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/).

Comment: I think taht,i must get before encashment date for every row.

Comment: Is the HTML posted in your question the source of data or did you try to place a formatted table within your quesiton?

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data as DDL+DML (create table and insert into statements) and desired results as human-readable text, indented 4 spaces so that it will be formatted properly.

Comment: I edited the question so that the HTML-table will be displayed via *run code snippet* But please clearify your question and read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
DECLARE @Encashment AS TABLE (MachineID INT, Amount INT, Occured DATETIME2)
DECLARE @MoneyAccepted AS TABLE (MachineID INT, Amount INT, Occured DATETIME2)

INSERT @Encashment (MachineID, Amount, Occured)
VALUES  (1, 101, '20171020 09:36:40.057')
,       (1, 203, '20171014 12:36:30.081')
,       (1, 400, '20171011 04:17:38.023')

INSERT @MoneyAccepted (MachineID, Amount, Occured)
VALUES  (1, 1, '20171015 09:36:40.057')
,       (1, 100, '20171016 12:36:30.081')
,       (1, 100, '20171012 16:17:38.023') 
,       (1, 100, '20171014 09:17:38.023')
,       (1, 1, '20171013 09:37:47.057')
,       (1, 1, '20171013 09:37:47.057')
,       (1, 1, '20171012 15:37:31.081') 

SELECT      E.Occured AS Encashment_Occured
,           SUM(MA.Amount) AS SUM_Amount
FROM        @MoneyAccepted AS MA
INNER JOIN (
                SELECT  MachineID
                ,       Amount
                ,       Occured
                ,       LAG(Occured) OVER(PARTITION BY MachineID ORDER BY Occured) AS Previous_Occured 
                FROM    @Encashment
            ) AS E
        ON  E.MachineID = MA.MachineID
        AND E.Occured > MA.Occured
        AND E.Previous_Occured <= MA.Occured
GROUP BY    E.Occured
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------------+------------+
|     Encashment_Occured      | SUM_Amount |
+-----------------------------+------------+
| 2017-10-14 12:36:30.0810000 |        203 |
| 2017-10-20 09:36:40.0570000 |        101 |
+-----------------------------+------------+
```

This uses [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql), which was introduced in sql server 2012, in order to get the range of applicable dates in a single row.

Comment: Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Please edit your question, remove html and use plain text for sample data.

I think you could use CROSS APPLY.
Try this:

```
WITH Encashment AS (
    SELECT  T.MachineId, T.Amount, CAST(Occured AS DATETIME) AS Occured
    FROM (VALUES 
          (1, 101, '2017-10-20 09:36:40.057')
         ,(1, 203, '2017-10-14 12:36:30.081')
         ,(1, 400, '2017-10-11 04:17:38.023')
         ) AS T(MachineId, Amount, Occured)
), MoneyAccepted  AS (
    SELECT  T.MachineId, T.Amount, CAST(Occured AS DATETIME) AS Occured
    FROM (VALUES 
          (1, 1, '2017-10-15 09:36:40.057')
         ,(1, 100, '2017-10-16 12:36:30.081')
         ,(1, 100, '2017-10-12 16:17:38.023')
         ,(1, 1, '2017-10-13 09:37:47.057')
         ,(1, 1, '2017-10-13 09:37:47.057')
         ,(1, 1, '2017-10-12 15:37:47.057')
         ,(1, 100, '2017-09-15 12:37:31.081')
         ,(1, 100, '2017-09-15 16:37:31.081')
         ,(1, 100, '2017-09-16 13:37:31.081')
         ,(1, 100, '2017-09-17 13:37:31.081')
         ) AS T(MachineId, Amount, Occured)
)
SELECT M.*, EN.* 
FROM MoneyAccepted AS M
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) E.* FROM Encashment AS E
    WHERE E.MachineId = M.MachineId AND E.Occured > M.Occured
    ORDER BY E.Occured ASC
) AS EN
```